# Is this code vulnerable to any attack?

Tags: web-application

I found the following code on [this page](http://www.joboulot.com/IN/+/Artson-Engineering-Ltd-#job-list). Is this indicative of a security problem.

```
;}else{str=" Following ";}
document.getElementById("follow_"+count).innerHTML=str;} 
function checkLoginForFollowWidget(root_imageurl,company_id,flag,count)
{ajaxController.isUserAuthenticated(function(response){if(response!=null){i
```

I got this when I submitted `null` search box. Is this a vulnerability? I think displaying the code on the main page is like code is getting exposed on the webpage?

When I put this in Google search, I get many websites having such information on their webpage.

Comment: Is this your code? Please provide additional information. It uses AJAX and we do not know how the serverside code looks like. I do not see any real results for ajaxController.isUserAuthenticate in Google.

Comment: For me it looks like a social media widget (Twitter?). I think there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: This i got displayed on the main webpage while i submited null by writing "null" in search button so is this vulnerable because i think displaying the code on the main page is like code is getting exposed on the webpage ??

Comment: @DanielRuf Please let me know

Comment: Please provide further details where you got the code from, how you implement it and how your search works. null is so far not dangerous. If you mean XSS, there are many known strings to test for XSS. Please provide some URL if possible.

Comment: The search may have given the code because it contains the null value but this is harmless. The code does not contain any important data. You just see some part of the sourcecode. I just found parts of the code on some weird job platforms and saw it in one job posting. But this should be harmless as there is nothing executed in this case. Maybe someone accidentally pasted it into a job posting.

Comment: Yes, if you go to http://www.joboulot.com/IN/+/Artson-Engineering-Ltd-#job-list  you will be able to see that. I wanted to know why such code is being displayed on the main webpage, because of what reason. is it they included the code along with the link name in h ref tag by mistakely ??

Comment: I updated the question based on comments to make it complete.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be by mistake, I saw it on many of these small job boards / platforms but not on other websites.

The code looks like some part of a social media widget which was pasted in a job posting by accident as it seems.

Also the code is harmless.